# Использование __ и ____ в PHP

Tags: php

Проходил тест и там были вопросы, которые я не понял.

1. Для чего используется  __ (скорее всего это два подчеркивания) ? Ответ - используется для обозначения магических методов не верен. Вот и вопрос для чего еще.
2. _____ (наверное четыре подчеркивания) используется для валидации и очистки: $_REQUEST или $_SERVER или $_GET или $_COOKIES. В просторах интернета что-то такого не нахожу. Поясните

Comment: четыре подчеркивания. но не подряд `__DIR__`

Comment: Два подчёркивания используются во многих фреймворках как функция интернационализации. __( 'text') возвращет перевод.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.magic.php
Это магические методы.

А можно ссылку на тест, просто про 4 подчеркивания ни разу не слышал.
и про то, что два подчеркивания-это не магические методы.

Comment: на UpWork PHP test

Comment: Нашел там только ответы